# Calendar doesn't displayed using sfJQueryUIPlugin

Tags: jquery, forms, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I have installed the sfJQueryUIPlugin for my project, which I want to display a date picker for a birthday selection. therefore after installation I've change my form widgets to

```
"date_of_birth" =>new sfWidgetFormDateJQueryUI(array("change_month" => true, "change_year" => true)),
```

But when I viewing the template it only appears a input box. No calender displaying.

Any idea?

[This is plugin  which i used sfJQueryUIPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfJQueryUIPlugin)
Is there any other way or plugin which i can use as a date picker for symfony ... please give me an idea..

Comment: Are the jquery and jquery UI libraries loaded? Any javascript errors?

Comment: You can also use the sfWidgetFormJQueryDate widget from the sfFormExtraPlugin plugin (http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfFormExtraPlugin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use js and css from plugins you should execute this command:

```
php symfony plugin:publish-assets
```

This will copy the files in your web folder.

For a better explanation check the assets section in http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Propel/en/20

Answer (score 0):

You can add normal text widget to the form with id="date_of_birth" and simply use javascript slot wit jQuery (in view template):

```
<?php append_to_slot('javascript'); ?>

  $(function() {
    $("#date_of_birth").datepicker();
  });

<?php end_append_to_slot(); ?>
```

Comment: Instead of using `>` to highlight your code, you should use 4 spaces, it will have a better render.